# How to change Windows 2012 screen resolution to 800x600?

Tags: vmware-workstation, windows-server-2012

I have set up Windows Server 2012 for testing purposes in VMWare Workstation.
One of our test requires changing the screen resolution to 800x600.
Server 2012 offers 1024x768 as minimum screen size. However, the graphic cards adapter "List all modes" shows 800x600 in the list.

How can I set the screen resolution to 800x600?

> VMWare Workstation 10.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to graphic cards adapter, "List all modes", choose a mode, click OK and click OK again.

I didn't realize this immediately.